# How to check is password field exists in a desktop GUI application?

Tags: c#, c++, user-interface

I am working in Desktop GUI Application. Is there any way to check the desktop GUI application has password field or not from c++ or c#? I wan it only for desktop based not for browser based window application?.

If it is possible, can I access those elements means controls?

Comment: Why? Are you trying to write a password stealing app?

Comment: Is it windows forms application  you working on?

Comment: No @RemusRusanu I have to auto fill the user id and password. so i have to access those elements?? is there any ways to do??

Comment: Yes @Thakur Like SAP client, outlook, Lotus note

Answer (score 1):

In classic Windows (Winforms, Win32), once you get the `HWND` you can check for the [`ES_PASSWORD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464(v=vs.85).aspx) window style.

Nowadays, it is not that simple though, since there are multiple UI technologies being used for various applications. In general, you would need to find out if the app uses Winforms, WPF, QT, HTML5, XUL, or some other tech, and each has its own edit control.

If the app is well-behaved, you may be able to use [UI automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.controltype.edit(v=vs.110).aspx) to fill the password field. IIRC, Winforms and WPF apps implements UI automation by default.

Comment: Can i access lotus notes control elements ?? @Krumelur

Comment: That depends on how Lotus notes is implemented. UISpy is a good tool to check if an app supports UI Automation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms727247(v=vs.100).aspx